# Is this implementation of Kruskal's algorithm maintainable and efficient?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, graph

I'm implementing [Kruskal's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm) in C++11 and would like feedback on style and performance on my graph data structure and algorithm for educational purposes (for production code, I'd use a pre-existing library). The main design questions I have are:

Is there a better way to implement the handle class for the graph structure?
Did I implement path compression correctly in the `UnionFind` data structure?

I also have a couple of C++11 specific questions:

1. Am I applying move semantics in a useful way when I add vertices and edges?
2. Am I taking full advantage of return value optimization and copy elision?

**AdjacencyList.h**

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

#include "FwdDecl.h"
#include "Handle.h"
#include "Vertex.h"
#include "Edge.h"

class AdjacencyList
{
public:
    typedef Vertex vertex_type;
    typedef std::string vertex_id_type;
    typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<vertex_type>> vertex_container;
    typedef Handle<vertex_type> vertex_handle;

    typedef Edge<vertex_handle> edge_type;
    typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<edge_type>> edge_container;
    typedef Handle<edge_type> edge_handle;

    vertex_container getVertexList() const
    {
        return m_vertices;
    }

    edge_container getEdgeList() const
    {
        return m_edges;
    }

    size_t getNumVerts() const
    {
        return m_vertices.size();
    }

    size_t getNumEdges() const
    {
        return m_edges.size();
    }

    vertex_handle findVertex(const vertex_type& v) const
    {
        return findVertexById(v.m_id);
    }

    vertex_handle findVertexById(const vertex_id_type& id) const
    {
        const auto vertexIt(std::find_if(begin(m_vertices), 
                                         end(m_vertices), 
                                         [id](const std::shared_ptr<vertex_type>& v) { return v->m_id == id; } ));

        vertex_handle result(std::shared_ptr<vertex_type>(nullptr), 0);

        if (vertexIt != end(m_vertices))
        {
            result = vertex_handle(*vertexIt, std::distance(begin(m_vertices), vertexIt));
        }

        return result;
    }

    edge_handle findEdge(const edge_type& e) const
    {
        return findEdge(e.getStart(), e.getEnd(), e.getWeight());
    }

    edge_handle findEdge(const vertex_handle& startVertex, const vertex_handle& endVertex, size_t weight) const
    {
        return findEdge(startVertex->m_id, endVertex->m_id, weight);
    }

    edge_handle findEdge(const vertex_id_type& startId, const vertex_id_type& endId, size_t weight) const
    {
        const auto edgeIt(std::find_if(begin(m_edges),
                                       end(m_edges),
                                       [startId, endId, weight](const std::shared_ptr<edge_type>& e)
                                       { return weight  == e->getWeight()      &&
                                                startId == e->getStart()->m_id &&
                                                endId   == e->getEnd()->m_id;
                                       } ));

        edge_handle result(std::shared_ptr<edge_type>(nullptr), 0);

        if (edgeIt != end(m_edges))
        {
            result = edge_handle(*edgeIt, std::distance(begin(m_edges), edgeIt));
        }

        return result;
    }

    vertex_handle addVertex(const vertex_type& v)
    {
        auto existingVertex(findVertex(v));

        if (!existingVertex.isValid())
        {
            m_vertices.push_back(std::make_shared<vertex_type>(v));
            existingVertex = vertex_handle(m_vertices.back(), m_vertices.size() - 1);
        }

        return existingVertex;
    }

    vertex_handle addVertex(vertex_type&& v)
    {
        auto existingVertex(findVertex(v));

        if (!existingVertex.isValid())
        {
            m_vertices.push_back(std::make_shared<vertex_type>(std::move(v)));
            existingVertex = vertex_handle(m_vertices.back(), m_vertices.size() - 1);
        }

        return existingVertex;
    }

    edge_handle addEdge(const edge_type& e)
    {
        auto existingEdge(findEdge(e));

        if (!existingEdge.isValid())
        {
            m_edges.push_back(std::make_shared<edge_type>(e));
            existingEdge = edge_handle(m_edges.back(), m_edges.size() - 1);
        }

        return existingEdge;
    }

    edge_handle addEdge(edge_type&& e)
    {
        auto existingEdge(findEdge(e));

        if (!existingEdge.isValid())
        {
            m_edges.push_back(std::make_shared<edge_type>(std::move(e)));
            existingEdge = edge_handle(m_edges.back(), m_edges.size() - 1);
        }

        return existingEdge;
    }
private:
    vertex_container    m_vertices;
    edge_container      m_edges;
};
```

**Handle.h**

```
#include <memory>
#include <exception>

template <typename T>
class Handle
{
public:
    Handle(const std::shared_ptr<T>& ptr, size_t index)
        : m_ptr(ptr)
        , m_index(index)
    {

    }

    bool isValid() const
    {
        return !m_ptr.expired();
    }

    size_t getIndex() const
    {
        if (isValid())
        {
            return m_index;
        }

        throw std::logic_error("Attempt to get index from invalid handle.");
    }

    T& operator*()
    {
        const auto ptr = m_ptr.lock();
        if (ptr)
        {
            return *ptr;
        }

        throw std::logic_error("Attempt to dereference invalid handle.");
    }

    const T& operator*() const
    {
        const auto ptr = m_ptr.lock();
        if (ptr)
        {
            return *ptr;
        }

        throw std::logic_error("Attempt to dereference invalid handle.");
    }

    T* operator->()
    {
        const auto ptr = m_ptr.lock();
        if (ptr)
        {
            return ptr.get();
        }

        return nullptr;
    }

    const T* operator->() const
    {
        const auto ptr = m_ptr.lock();
        if (ptr)
        {
            return ptr.get();
        }

        return nullptr;
    }
private:
    std::weak_ptr<T> m_ptr;
    size_t           m_index;
};
```

**Kruskal.cpp**

```
#include "Kruskal.h"
#include "AdjacencyList.h"
#include "UnionFind.h"

AdjacencyList kruskal(const AdjacencyList& graph)
{
    auto edges(graph.getEdgeList());
    std::sort(begin(edges), 
              end(edges),
              [](const AdjacencyList::edge_container::value_type& lhs,
                 const AdjacencyList::edge_container::value_type& rhs)
                 {
                     return *lhs < *rhs;
                 });

    UnionFind components(graph.getNumVerts());
    AdjacencyList minimumSpanningTree;

    for (const auto edgePtr : edges)
    {
        const auto* edge = edgePtr.get();

        const auto startIndex = edge->getStart().getIndex();
        const auto endIndex = edge->getEnd().getIndex();
        if (!components.sameComponent(startIndex, endIndex))
        {
            const auto startVertex(minimumSpanningTree.addVertex(*edge->getStart()));
            const auto endVertex(minimumSpanningTree.addVertex(*edge->getEnd()));
            minimumSpanningTree.addEdge(AdjacencyList::edge_type(startVertex,
                                                                 endVertex,
                                                                 edge->getWeight()));

            components.merge(startIndex, endIndex);
        }
    }

    return minimumSpanningTree;
}
```

**UnionFind.h**

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <exception>
#include <sstream>

class UnionFind
{
public:
    explicit UnionFind(size_t numVerts)
    {
        m_components.reserve(numVerts);
        size_t parentIdx = 0;
        std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(m_components),
                        numVerts,
                        [&]() { return UnionFindNode(parentIdx++); });
    }

    bool sameComponent(size_t start, size_t end) const
    {
        return findRoot(start) == findRoot(end);
    }

    size_t findRoot(size_t elem) const
    {
        if (elem < m_components.size())
        {
            auto prevParent = elem;
            auto parentIdx = m_components[prevParent].parentIdx;

            while (parentIdx != prevParent)
            {
                prevParent = parentIdx;
                parentIdx = m_components[parentIdx].parentIdx;
            }

            return parentIdx;
        }

        std::ostringstream oss;
        oss << "Element index " << elem << " is out of range of components buffer (size " << m_components.size() << ").";
        throw std::out_of_range(oss.str());
    }

    void merge(size_t start, size_t end)
    {
        const auto startRoot(findRoot(start));
        const auto endRoot(findRoot(end));

        if (startRoot == endRoot)
        {
            return;
        }

        const auto startTreeSize = m_components[startRoot].subtreeSize;
        const auto endTreeSize   = m_components[endRoot].subtreeSize;

        if (startTreeSize < endTreeSize)
        {
            m_components[startRoot].parentIdx = m_components[endRoot].parentIdx;
        }
        else
        {
            m_components[endRoot].parentIdx = m_components[startRoot].parentIdx;
        }

        if (startTreeSize == endTreeSize)
        {
            m_components[startRoot].subtreeSize += 1;
        }
    }
private:
    struct UnionFindNode
    {
        explicit UnionFindNode(size_t parent)
            : parentIdx(parent)
            , subtreeSize(1)
        {

        }

        size_t parentIdx;
        size_t subtreeSize;
    };

    std::vector<UnionFindNode> m_components;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest I am having a hard time following your code.
So I can't comment on the efficiency.

But as an engineer I will make comments on maintainability (which I think is much more important (because if you understand the code you can optimize the slow parts once you have measured it))

I am not sure I understand the difference between "vertex_type" and "edge_type"?.

```
typedef Vertex vertex_type;
typedef std::string vertex_id_type;
typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<vertex_type>> vertex_container;
typedef Handle<vertex_type> vertex_handle;

typedef Edge<vertex_handle> edge_type;
typedef std::vector<std::shared_ptr<edge_type>> edge_container;
typedef Handle<edge_type> edge_handle;
```

Getters are bad OO design. They expose and thus bind your implementation to specific types.

```
vertex_container getVertexList() const
edge_container   getEdgeList()   const
size_t getNumVerts() const
size_t getNumEdges() const
```

Also you are returning the result by value (and thus copying) when you could return a const reference achieving the same affect without copying.

I am not sure what `Handle` is.
In computer science terms a Handle is named resource (thus allowing the resource to be moved and the handle to still refer to the same thing (commonly implemented as a pointer to a pointer to the resource)).

I handle you violate the "DRY" principle:

this code (or simple variations of it) are reeated multiple times.:

```
    const auto ptr = m_ptr.lock();
    if (ptr)
    {
        return <SIMPLE ACTION>;
    }

    throw std::logic_error(<ERROR MESSAGE>);
```

Comment: why would vertex be a synonym for edge?

Comment: @Ysangkok: Ops. Long time since I did geometry.